# NetBeans 8.2 not showing "Design", "Source", "History" and "JDBC Properties" Buttons in "hibernate.cfg"

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, netbeans

NetBeans 8.2 not showing "Design", "Source", "History" and "JDBC Properties" Buttons in "hibernate.cfg"

[image]

Need it like below:

[image]

Do anyone know how to make them visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Go to  view>>show editor toolbar

that's worked for me!